# Is there a way to pass objects connected to hardware to Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I would like to test a hardware device with the Robot Framework. Since I do not want to disconnect and connect my device every test case again, I would like to know if there is a possibility to have a Python object initialized outside of the Robot Framework but used inside it.

See my code exapmle as follows:

Main.py:

```
from robot import run
from SomeLibraryUsedByRobot import SomeLibraryUsedByRobot

device = Device()
SomeLibraryUsedByRobot.device = device

run('SomeRobotFile.robot')
```

SomeLibraryUsedByRobot.py:

```
class SomeLibraryUsedByRobot:
    device = None

    def access_device(self):
        device.some_function()
```

SomeRobotFile.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             SomeLibraryUsedByRobot.py

*** Test Cases ***  
Some Test
    Access Device
```

The execution of the main file results in the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute some_function` what brings me to the conclusion that the initialization of the field `device` of the library inside the main file is not working.

I also tried out my plans using the listener interface of the robot framework and its function `library_import(self, name, attributes)`.

MyListener.py:

```
class MyListener:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def library_import(self, name, attributes):
        if name == "SomeLibraryUsedByRobot":
            device = Device()
            SomeLibraryUsedByRobot.device = device
            print( "SomeLibraryUsedByRobot initialized with device" )
```

When I tried it with the listener, I executed the robot file directly from console (and not with the main.py). I also added a line inside the library class: `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'`.

The `library_import(...)` function definitely gets called, since I am seeing the print on the console. But the result is the same with the first try: `'NoneType' object has no attribute some_function`.

Basically, we do not have to involve any hardware in this discussion. I just would like to pass some python objects from outside to the libraries used by the robot framework. Do you see any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a keyword to open/init the device and a keyword to close/deinit the device inside your `SomeLibraryUsedByRobot`.

```
class SomeLibraryUsedByRobot:

    # Called upon library import for more: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-scope
    def __init__(self):
        self.device = None

    def access_device(self):
        self.device.some_function()

    def init_device(self):
        self.device = Device()

    def deinit_device(self):
        self.device.deinit()
        self.device = None
```

Now to avoid connecting, disconnecting in every test case call these keywords in the [Suite Setup/Suite Teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown).

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SomeLibraryUsedByRobot
Suite Setup       Init Device
Suite Teardown    Deinit Device

*** Test Cases ***
Case 1
    Access Device

Case 2
    Access Device

Case 3
    Access Device

Case 4
    Access Device
```

Generally apply the approach used in other existing libraries like Telnet or SeleniumLibrary where there are `Open ...` and `Close ...` keywords to manage connections to a browser or in case of Telnet to a server or a hardware, etc.

With multiple devices you can use the [robot.utils.connectioncache](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0/_modules/robot/utils/connectioncache.html) to manage multiple connections. This is used by many existing libraries out there.